# Calculator for CPU/GPU charge of a website

Tags: web, gpu, cpu

I would like to know if there is a way to know precisely the CPU and GPU charge of a website without taking care about the navigator.

Comment: What do you mean by "the CPU and GPU charge"?

Comment: To do simpler, I take an exemple. If there is a website with WebGl and another website juste with html an css I would like to calculate the difference of CPU and GPU utilisation between this two sites.